# How to take input from file containing string and integer?

Tags: c, input

I am trying to get an input from a text file,whose name is of the format 
(without spaces) .Eg, 3shop where 3 is number of inputs in file.
How do I extract this number from the string ?

Also content of the file is of same format and variable length.
**i.e complete 3shop.txt is of the form
1soap 3toothpate 5biscuits
8biscuits
9toothpaste 5 soap

There  is no limit on size of integer,otherwise i could have used an array and extracted the number.
Please, suggest some good ways to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "**I am trying** to get an input from a text file..." Then show what you have tried as well as what the expected and actual results are.

Comment: one shop data by one line ?

Answer (score 1):

```
char name[32] = "3shop.txt", *p = name;
long id;

id = strtol(name, &p, 10);
printf("id=%ld name=%s\n", id, p);
```

`10` in `strtol` means base 10 (decimal)

After the call to `strtol`, `p` points to the next character in `name` after the numerical value